# Azure Translator Text - Exclude Wrong Detected Language

Tags: microsoft-translator

1. Using example at https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/cognitive-services/translator/quickstart-csharp-translate
2. When I key in "Apa Khabar", it get detected language as ID with score of 1.0, but actually I want the language as MS so that our system can process it properly. Because the translated text has different meaning.

Apa khabar in ID = What are the rumors?
Apa khabar in MS = How are you?

3. Is there a way to exclude ID language when I use the API?

Thanks.

Searched for method to exclude language in the documentation

```
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            // This is our main function.
            // Output languages are defined in the route.
            // For a complete list of options, see API reference.
            // https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-translate
            string host = "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com";
            string route = "/translate?api-version=3.0&to=en";
            string subscriptionKey = "XXX";
            // Prompts you for text to translate. If you'd prefer, you can
            // provide a string as textToTranslate.
            Console.Write("Type the phrase you'd like to translate? ");
            string textToTranslate = Console.ReadLine();
            await TranslateTextRequest(subscriptionKey, host, route, textToTranslate);
        }

        // This sample requires C# 7.1 or later for async/await.
        // Async call to the Translator Text API
        static public async Task TranslateTextRequest(string subscriptionKey, string host, string route, string inputText)
        {
            /*
             * The code for your call to the translation service will be added to this
             * function in the next few sections.
             */

            object[] body = new object[] { new { Text = inputText } };
            var requestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage())
            {
                // In the next few sections you'll add code to construct the request.
                // Build the request.
                // Set the method to Post.
                request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
                // Construct the URI and add headers.
                request.RequestUri = new Uri(host + route);
                request.Content = new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                request.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);

                // Send the request and get response.
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
                // Read response as a string.
                string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                // Deserialize the response using the classes created earlier.
                TranslationResult[] deserializedOutput = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TranslationResult[]>(result);
                // Iterate over the deserialized results.
                foreach (TranslationResult o in deserializedOutput)
                {
                    // Print the detected input language and confidence score.
                    Console.WriteLine("Detected input language: {0}\nConfidence score: {1}\n", o.DetectedLanguage.Language, o.DetectedLanguage.Score);
                    // Iterate over the results and print each translation.
                    foreach (Translation t in o.Translations)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Translated to {0}: {1}", t.To, t.Text);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Get detected language as ID instead of MS
So the translated sentence become "What are the rumors" instead of "how are you"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Detect function and the Translate function return an array of languages with probabilities. 
In the case of Detect you'd have to filter the languages you do not want in the response object.
In case of Translate returning an undesired language, you will have to re-issue the translation, forcing the desired language.

Comment: Thanks. It only returns one language which is ID. So, I re-translate again with MS manually if the system detected ID.